# Add <span> after <a>

Tags: jquery

Hi I am using below jquery to add span after anchor tag.

Below is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a.ext-or-pdf-link").append("<span class=test>test</span>");
});
```

But this is adding span inside `<a>` tag but i want to add after `<a>` in such a way `<a ...> text </a><span class=test>test</span>`.

Any Idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
$("a.ext-or-pdf-link").after("<span class=test>test</span>");
```

[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) adds the passed elements as the last child of the targeted element. So in your case the `span` will be added as the last child of the `anchor` instead of adding it as the next sibling

Answer (score 2):

Use `after` instead of `append`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a.ext-or-pdf-link").after("<span class=test>test</span>");
});
```

Comment: Hi, No idea but when i refresh my page span removes.

Answer (score 0):

Use after()

```
$("a.ext-or-pdf-link").after("<span class=test>test</span>");
```

Please refer to the link : http://api.jquery.com/after/

Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.